# How to separate location listener and Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, location, locationlistener

I am trying to make a location tracking application on an android phone, it will be just same as the built-in google map in the phone. It will continue to track the phone even the app is close, so it will be running in the background of other applications.

I am thinking of splitting up both the classes, User Interface (Google Map) and location tracking, where the location tracking will always run but the google map will only display when the user open the application. Thus this is what I reached so far.

MapDisplay class for Google Map

```
public class MapDisplay extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationService locationService;
    private Intent locationServiceIntent;

    private Location myLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_display);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        locationServiceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        x=0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startService(locationServiceIntent);
        bindService(locationServiceIntent, locationServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateLocation()
    {
        // for testing purpose, to make sure it will update periodically
        Toast.makeText(MapDisplay.this, String.valueOf(myLocation.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private ServiceConnection locationServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            locationService = ((LocationService.LocationBinder)service).getService();
            myLocation = locationService.getMyLocation();
            updateLocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
             locationService = null;
        }
    };
}
```

LocationService class

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener
{

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location myLocation;
    private IBinder locationBinder = new LocationBinder();

    public class LocationBinder extends Binder
    {
        public LocationService getService()
        {
            return LocationService.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return locationBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        locationManager   = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocation = null;

        boolean networkProviderAvailable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        boolean gpsProviderAvailable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(networkProviderAvailable)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
        else if(gpsProviderAvailable)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
        else
        {
            stopSelf();
        }  
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public Location getMyLocation()
    {
        return myLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        myLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

Using code above I experienced application crash because of this line

```
myLocation = locationService.getMyLocation();
String.valueOf(myLocation.getLatitude())
```

It can't get the location from LocationService class.

So, my questions are:

- 1) is this a good way to make the application?
- 2) how to periodically call the updateLocation() in MapDisplay when there are new updates in onLocationChanged method?

I will be much appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for the case that you have not yet received a location.  To do that, your client code needs to check the return of getLocation for null, and handle accordingly.

Additionally you may want some more intelligence in onLocationChanged.  Right now if a gps location comes in and then a network location comes in, the network location will overwrite the gps location, despite being less accurate.  I'd take a look at some code I wrote at http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/   You'll see a class FallbackLocationTracker which will track both gps and network location, returning the most accurate location received so far.  I think it does what you're trying to do.